# Write an atomic operation

Tags: ruby, transactions, ruby-1.9, atomic

I would like to execute some methods atomicity with Ruby, according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_(database_systems)

For instance, if I have:

```
a = 30
b = 75
```

I would like to be able to do something like:

```
atomic_operation do
  a += 10
  b -= 39
end
```

Is there a native module in Ruby 1.9 that allow such process?  If possible, I would like to do so without using a plugin.  Many thanks!

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/headius/ruby-atomic and inside http://pragprog.com/book/jsthreads/working-with-ruby-threads

Answer (score 8):

It really depends on the scope you are interested in as to the right tools for the job.  If you are looking to perform an atomic operation on a database, then the database driver will probably (if it's any good/the database supports it) offer a way to use a database transaction to make updates atomic.

If you are talking about a multi-threaded Ruby application attempting to makes updates to shared resources atomic and thread-safe, then Ruby provides the Mutex and ConditionVariable classes to help you out in that regard.
(More info: http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_threads.html)

Comment: Also check out the `Monitor` and `MonitorMixin` classes that are part of the Ruby standard libraries.

Answer (score 7):

The Mutex class is available in the 1.9 runtime (and `require('thread')` in 1.8) and allows you to lock operations in a context.

```
# Typically defined in the object initializer
@lock = Mutex.new

# Then in your code
@lock.synchronize do
  a += 10
  b -= 39
end
```

This will guarantee you that the block given to Mutex#synchronize is run sequentially.

Official doc is here: http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/1.9.2/Mutex

Answer (score 6):

As you point to an article about databases, I'm guessing you are asking in this context.

If you are using Rails, you use the `transaction` [methods](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#locking-records-for-update) of [ActiveRecord](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html#M001361).

```
Account.transaction do
  @alice.withdraw!(100)
  @bob.deposit!(100)
end
```

If using outside of Rails, you have to work with what the database driver library provides. Check the [implementation of transaction](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb) on Rails to get an idea of how it can be done.

Answer (score 2):

What you need my friend is a Software transactional memory. Try out the STM implementation I have been playing with in JRuby (You need to checkout the code in repo as I haven't packaged it for the release).

Also check out Ruby atomic I am working on http://github.com/saivenkat/ruby-atomic. Gives you CAS type of operations on MRI. This is a bit lower level but will help you with the same problem. I haven't written Transactional Memory for MRI one but with the CAS infrastructure it won't be long :)

P.S Stackoverflow doesn't let me post more than one link as I didn't use its system a lot. So checkout the multiverse site in codehaus for STM in JRuby

--Sai Venkat

Comment: +1 for STM being what the OP needs. Haven't tried the library though.

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at the 'Transaction Simple' gem?

I think that would suit your purpose

http://rubyforge.org/projects/trans-simple